# Can I set a function as criteria in an autofilter in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, autofilter

What I want to do is, I want to filter a range by an `Autofilter`. The criteria is the `Vlookup` returns value `#N/A` or not. I need to handle this language independent. The English return value of `Vlookup` is `#N/A` and the German return value of `Vlookup` is `#NV`, therefore I want to use the function `WorksheetFunction.IsNA(arg)`.

Is it possible to use this function as criteria for an `Autofilter` in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > > The criteria is the Vlookup returns value #N/A

If it is only about `#N/A` then the suggestion given by KyleNZ will work. But if you want to trap all the error that `Vlookup` can return then use this

**Excel 2003**

```
=IF(ISERROR(arg),"",arg)
```

**Excel 2007 onwards**

```
=IFERROR(arg,"")
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help. 
For the reason that I'm just handle the #N/A will drive the following solution:
`'Much stuff
 'Non language dependent

deleteCrit_NullDiv = "=#DIV/0!"

'Language dependent

deleteCrit_ForLookupCanNotFound = languageHelper.GetForLookUpCanNotFound

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$30:$AO$4000").AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:=deleteCrit_NullDiv, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=deleteCrit_ForLookupCanNotFound

'Much more stuff`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an obvious way to do this in Excel 2003.

What you might try is adding an extra column, `IsInvalid`, with formula `=ISNA(<ref>)` where `<ref>` points to the cell with the lookup return value. You can then filter this to `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or the German equivalents).